# How can I do a 300-yard drift?

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

My current racer Speedlist (rank 18 "Drive") tells me to perform a single drift of at least 300 yards in length. However, I can't seem to find any good spots in the world to do it. A Google search tells me that some people have had success with a "clover-shaped freeway area" but even with that description I can't find a place that really sticks out to me as an ideal place to try. (Screenshots or video would be especially helpful.)

My current car is a Lamborghini Aventador with a pretty high Control stat. Is it possible to complete this goal with that car, or is there another car available below rank 18 that's easier to drift with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start there and climb up to the freeway. Then start making a 360 degree turn on the ramp above.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any car can drift, as I also had the same problem try starting at the auto shop closest to the area called 'sun valley run' drive the same direction the game puts you in and as you come to the first corner look to the left of your screen and you should see a white flat area... go for a spin and see if it helps tou out